# How to write a nested dictionary to json

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I created a nested dictionary in Python like this:

```
{
 "Laptop": {
            "sony": 1
            "apple": 2
            "asus": 5
          },
 "Camera": {
            "sony": 2
            "sumsung": 1
            "nikon" : 4
           },
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to write this nested dict into a json file. Any comments will be appreciated..!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
d = {
 "Laptop": {
            "sony": 1,
            "apple": 2,
            "asus": 5,
          },
 "Camera": {
            "sony": 2,
            "sumsung": 1,
            "nikon" : 4,
           },
}
with open("my.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(d,f)
```

Comment: If you would like to access, for example, the value of Sony (the camera), how could you do it?

Comment: this is about outputting data... to read it in you would use `json.loads` and then access it just like a normal dictionary(after loading it is just a dictionary)

Comment: @M.K - One not so pretty way of doing that would be `print(d.get('Camera').get('sony'))`. But it does the job!