# convert key/values in dicts and sub-dicts/arrays of bytes type to normal strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am receiving msgpack type data from an API and when I use `msgpack.unpackb` on the response I get a dict that contains sub-dicts or sub-arrays in which some keys and values are of type bytes, int and str, dict, list. I want to convert all of them to str but with meta information so I can convert them back to what they exactly were after I send them through web socket to the client.

Here is a sample data:

```py
{b'type': b'exploit', b'name': b'ibstat $PATH Privilege Escalation', b'fullname': b'exploit/aix/local/ibstat_path', b'rank': b'excellent', b'disclosuredate': b'2013-09-24', b'description': b'This module exploits the trusted $PATH environment variable of the SUID binary "ibstat".', b'license': b'Metasploit Framework License (BSD)', b'filepath': '/opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/framework/modules/exploits/aix/local/ibstat_path.rb', b'arch': [b'cmd'], b'platform': ['Msf::Module::Platform::Unix'], b'authors': [b'Kristian Erik Hermansen', b'Sagi Shahar <sagi.shahar@mwrinfosecurity.com>', b'Kostas Lintovois <kostas.lintovois@mwrinfosecurity.com>'], b'privileged': False, b'references': [[b'CVE', b'2013-4011'], [b'OSVDB', b'95420'], [b'BID', b'61287'], [b'URL', b'http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IV43827'], [b'URL', b'http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IV43756']], b'targets': {0: b'IBM AIX Version 6.1', 1: b'IBM AIX Version 7.1'}, b'default_target': 1, b'stance': b'aggressive', b'options': {b'WORKSPACE': {b'type': b'string', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Specify the workspace for this module'}, b'VERBOSE': {b'type': b'bool', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Enable detailed status messages', b'default': False}, b'WfsDelay': {b'type': b'integer', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Additional delay when waiting for a session', b'default': 0}, b'EnableContextEncoding': {b'type': b'bool', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Use transient context when encoding payloads', b'default': False}, b'ContextInformationFile': {b'type': b'path', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'The information file that contains context information'}, b'DisablePayloadHandler': {b'type': b'bool', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Disable the handler code for the selected payload', b'default': False}, b'SESSION': {b'type': b'integer', b'required': True, b'advanced': False, b'desc': b'The session to run this module on.'}, b'FileDropperDelay': {b'type': b'integer', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Delay in seconds before attempting cleanup'}, b'WritableDir': {b'type': b'string', b'required': True, b'advanced': False, b'desc': b'A directory where we can write files', b'default': b'/tmp'}}}
```

The nearest possible result I have achieved is that I can convert it yo what I want unless there are not sub-arrays or sub-dict. Here is the output I achieved:

```py
[[{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'type'}, {'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'exploit'}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'name'}, {'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'ibstat $PATH Privilege Escalation'}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'fullname'}, {'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'exploit/aix/local/ibstat_path'}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'rank'}, {'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'excellent'}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'disclosuredate'}, {'type': 'bytes', 'value': '2013-09-24'}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'description'}, {'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'This module exploits the trusted $PATH environment variable of the SUID binary "ibstat".'}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'license'}, {'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'Metasploit Framework License (BSD)'}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'filepath'}, {'type': 'str', 'value': '/opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/framework/modules/exploits/aix/local/ibstat_path.rb'}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'arch'}, {'type': 'list', 'value': [b'cmd']}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'platform'}, {'type': 'list', 'value': ['Msf::Module::Platform::Unix']}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'authors'}, {'type': 'list', 'value': [b'Kristian Erik Hermansen', b'Sagi Shahar <sagi.shahar@mwrinfosecurity.com>', b'Kostas Lintovois <kostas.lintovois@mwrinfosecurity.com>']}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'privileged'}, {'type': 'bool', 'value': False}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'references'}, {'type': 'list', 'value': [[b'CVE', b'2013-4011'], [b'OSVDB', b'95420'], [b'BID', b'61287'], [b'URL', b'http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IV43827'], [b'URL', b'http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IV43756']]}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'targets'}, {'type': 'dict', 'value': {0: b'IBM AIX Version 6.1', 1: b'IBM AIX Version 7.1'}}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'default_target'}, {'type': 'int', 'value': 1}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'stance'}, {'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'aggressive'}], [{'type': 'bytes', 'value': 'options'}, {'type': 'dict', 'value': {b'WORKSPACE': {b'type': b'string', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Specify the workspace for this module'}, b'VERBOSE': {b'type': b'bool', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Enable detailed status messages', b'default': False}, b'WfsDelay': {b'type': b'integer', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Additional delay when waiting for a session', b'default': 0}, b'EnableContextEncoding': {b'type': b'bool', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Use transient context when encoding payloads', b'default': False}, b'ContextInformationFile': {b'type': b'path', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'The information file that contains context information'}, b'DisablePayloadHandler': {b'type': b'bool', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Disable the handler code for the selected payload', b'default': False}, b'SESSION': {b'type': b'integer', b'required': True, b'advanced': False, b'desc': b'The session to run this module on.'}, b'FileDropperDelay': {b'type': b'integer', b'required': False, b'advanced': True, b'desc': b'Delay in seconds before attempting cleanup'}, b'WritableDir': {b'type': b'string', b'required': True, b'advanced': False, b'desc': b'A directory where we can write files', b'default': b'/tmp'}}}]]
```

And here is the code that produces the above output:

```py
def encode_dict(res):
    for key, value in res.items():
        op = []
        if type(key).__name__ == "bytes":
            op.append({'type': type(key).__name__, 'value': key.decode('utf-8')})
        else:
            op.append({'type': type(key).__name__, 'value': key})
        if type(value).__name__ == "bytes":
            op.append({'type': type(value).__name__, 'value': value.decode('utf-8')})
        else:
            op.append({'type': type(value).__name__, 'value': value})
        decoded_res.append(op)
    return decoded_res
```

I want the output for nested dicts and nested-lists so there is no single "bytes" type value or key inside the dict.

Comment: This has already been solved. It's called JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a nested dictionary to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560433/how-to-write-a-nested-dictionary-to-json)

Comment: @mkrieger1 JSON cannot serialize "bytes" type objects that why I need to eliminate all "bytes" type keys/values

Comment: Why do you use bytes and not normal strings?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am receiving msgpack type data from an API and when I use msgpack.unpackb on the response I get these "bytes" type dicts and lists. That API isn't in my control so I don't have a choice.

Comment: Then you can immediately convert bytes to strings after receiving, before putting them into the dictionary.

Comment: @mkrieger1 please check the edited comment again to understand completely

Comment: Ok, this raises the question... why do you not just send the msgpack object without decoding and encoding it again? Isn't the point of msgpack to serialize structured data for sending it over the network, which seems like what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://msgpack-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#msgpack.Unpacker, `unpackb` has an option

> `raw` (bool) – If true, unpack msgpack raw to Python bytes. Otherwise, unpack to Python str by decoding with UTF-8 encoding (default)

You could use `raw=False` (which should be the default), which should result in a dictionary where bytes are decoded to strings.

Comment: I need that msgpack data in the same "bytes" type after I transfer them to client because that client expects that "bytes" type data to operate. I just need to eliminate "bytes" for JSON conversion but I also need to convert it back to their original state(some are bytes, some are string, some are dict or list) once it reaches client.