# How to write nested dictionary to JSON file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

```
ohlc={58072071: {datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 26, 23, 20):
                    {'high': 179.0, 'low': 179.0, 'open': 179.0, 'close': 179.0,
                     'volume': 2354}}}
```

How do I write this dictionary into a JSON file?

I am getting this error when I am dumping this to JSON file

```
    TypeError(f'keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, '
TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not datetime
```

Comment: That error is obvious cause you have `datetime` object in `json` data, and `datetime` object is not `json serializable`.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560433/how-to-write-a-nested-dictionary-to-json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a nested dictionary to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560433/how-to-write-a-nested-dictionary-to-json)

Comment: This answer specifies how to JSON serialize anything, including datetime specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable/36142844#36142844

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with nested dictionaries. What part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: These arent solving the problem

Comment: I am getting the same error as mentioned above

Comment: Could you add the code that triggers this error in your question?

Comment: You have to convert the `datetime` into something the `json` module understands — as shown in [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) in the documentation. In this case I'd suggest a string via [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

Comment: Thanks for your advice ,it got solved m i converted the DateTime using  strftime

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment the problem isn't due to there being nested dictionaries, it's because they contain data that don't map to the JSON objects shown in the [table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) in the `json` module's documentation.

Here's a way to automate their conversion to strings using the [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) function.

```
from datetime import datetime
import json


DATE_FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

def decode_dict(d):
    result = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(key, datetime):
            key = datetime.strftime(key, DATE_FMT)
        if isinstance(value, datetime):
            value = datetime.strftime(value, DATE_FMT)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            value = decode_dict(value)  # Recursive call.
        result.update({key: value})
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':

    ohlc = {58072071: {datetime(2021, 3, 26, 23, 20):
                        {'high': 179.0, 'low': 179.0, 'open': 179.0, 'close': 179.0,
                         'volume': 2354}}}

    print(json.dumps(decode_dict(ohlc)))
```

Output:

```
{"58072071": {"2021-03-26 23:20":
                {"high": 179.0, "low": 179.0, "open": 179.0, "close": 179.0,
                 "volume": 2354}}}
}
```